# Is a circle classified as an ellipse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, intuition, circles

I read that an ellipse had $2$ focal points. So, I thought if a circle had $2$ points that were simply infinitesimally close together wouldn't it be classified as an ellipse?

Comment: Yes, you can say that circle is a special case of an ellipse with coinciding semiaxis.

Comment: A circle is simply a degenerate ellipse, one in which the two focal points coincide.

Comment: I think to say that the foci are infinitesimally close is not a good way to say it. In circle, the foci are just the same point.

Comment: Not sure if this should be asked in another question but can you draw an ellipse (that is not a circle) using a a pair of compasses?

Comment: @anonymous No. You can draw an ellipse using two pins and a string though.

Comment: Mathematicians love this kind of thing. An ellipse has two foci; in a circle, the two foci are in the same place.  A straight line and a hyperbola always intersect one another at two points, but the points might be infinitely far away and they might be in the same place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. A circle is a special case of an ellipse.

The equation of an ellipse centered at the origin $(0,0)$ is: $$\left(\frac xa \right)^2 + \left(\frac yb \right)^2=1$$

When $a=b=1$, this gives the equation of the unit circle: $x^2+y^2=1$.

In general, if $a=b=r$, you get the equation of a circle with radius $r$: $$x^2+y^2=r^2$$

Can you come up the equation of a circle not centered at $(0,0)$, but instead centered at $(h,k)$?

Comment: But then $e=0$ for the ellipse, but ellipse have $0\lt e\lt1$. That's a contradiction.

Answer (score 10):

Both the foci of a circle coincide and thus, its eccentricity is zero. So yes, it is an ellipse. 
It is like that all squares are rectangles but all rectangles are not squares. 
See this link- [the most intuitive link ever seen!]
http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/eccentricity.html

Comment: All rectangles are squares in SOME coordinate system :-)